# javax.json.stream.JsonParsingException: Unexpected Char= Parse error during org.glassfish.json.JsonTokenizer.readString

Tags: java, json, websocket, glassfish, base64

Got this below exception trace during sending the json objects containing base64 image string using Encoder and Decoder over websockets.
From ClientEndpoint to ServerEndpoint

Question : How to avoid this or any alternate solution to send the base64 image strings over the websockets ?

```
import javax.websocket.EncodeException;
import javax.websocket.Encoder;
import javax.websocket.EndpointConfig;



public class MessageEncoder extends ServerObject implements    Encoder.Text<Message> {

    @Override
    public String encode(Message message) throws EncodeException {
        info("MessageEncoding -- {}",message.getJson());
        return message.getJson().toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void init(EndpointConfig config) {
        info("MessageEncoder init ");
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
       info("MessageEncoder destroy ");
    }

}
```

Loggable error:

```
5-03-27 20:42:15,290 INFO  [stdout] (default I/O-8) B^No^MW P>R&@^H!6^M^M
2015-03-27 20:42:15,290 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-8) javax.json.stream.JsonParsingException: Unexpected Char=31^M^M
2015-03-27 20:42:15,290 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-8)  at org.glassfish.json.JsonTokenizer.readString(JsonTokenizer.java:180)^M^M
2015-03-27 20:42:15,290 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-8)  at org.glassfish.json.JsonTokenizer.nextToken(JsonTokenizer.java:368)^M^M
2015-03-27 20:42:15,290 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-8)  at org.glassfish.json.JsonParserImpl.nextToken(JsonParserImpl.java:154)^M^M
2015-03-27 20:42:15,291 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-8)  at org.glassfish.json.JsonParserImpl.access$600(JsonParserImpl.java:60)^M^M
2015-03-27 20:42:15,291 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-8)  at org.glassfish.json.JsonParserImpl$ObjectContext.getNextEvent(JsonParserImpl.java:258)^M^M
2015-03-27 20:42:15,291 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-8)  at org.glassfish.json.JsonParserImpl$StateIterator.next(JsonParserImpl.java:180)^M^M
2015-03-27 20:42:15,291 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-8)  at org.glassfish.json.JsonParserImpl.next(JsonParserImpl.java:149)^M^M
2015-03-27 20:42:15,291 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-8)  at org.glassfish.json.JsonReaderImpl.readObject(JsonReaderImpl.java:176)^M
```

Comment: I think you need to share `ServerObject` and `Message`. In Jackson, `mapper.convertValue(data, String.class)` which means conversion from binary to string converts binary to base64 string but I'm not sure it's the same within `javax.json.stream`. if `javax.json.stream` doesn't support it, you need to deal with binary-to-text conversion using [Base64](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html) class which is available as of Java 8 by yourself. BTW, WebSocket allows to exchange binary message. You don't need to convert binary to text for that.

Comment: ServerObject is logger class inside my codebase, I avoided decoding the base64 images incoming on final tier (RemoteApp -> middle tier -> final tier), And used the sendBinary of the websockets api. Thanks alot for the help